# Guarded clause is still 'object is quite possible null'

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
if (calendarSelectedDayRef !== null) {
  calendarSelectedDayRef.current.focus();
}
```

I've recently enabled strict mode on TypeScript and I'm getting the error `Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)`

I've tried the following but all result in the same error:

```
if (calendarSelectedDayRef.current !== null) {
   calendarSelectedDayRef.current.focus();
}
```

```
calendarSelectedDayRef.current && calendarSelectedDayRef.current.focus();
```

```
calendarSelectedDayRef && calendarSelectedDayRef.current.focus();
```

The only change I made that gave a different error was:

```
calendarSelectedDayRef ?? calendarSelectedDayRef.current.focus();
```

which resulted in: `Property 'current' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)`

`calendarRef` looks like this `const calendarRef = useRef(null);`

I'm unsure as to how this is a valid error as surely the check before it shows that it's not null? Is this TypeScript bugging out or is it a valid catch, if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: A ref should always have a `current` property. Can you include a minimal but complete example of the component where this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the issue was related to it not realising it was a DOM element in the ref, I fixed the issue by changing:

```
const calendarRef = useRef(null);
```

to

```
const calendarRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

and then `calendarSelectedDayRef?.current?.focus();` worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `current` in calendarSelectedDayRef should be optional. Therefore, typescript remind you there is a chance `current` will be null.

Although there is a check of null explicitly, the `strict null checks` rule checks the code line by line and prompt you `Object is possibly null` error

```js
interface CalendarSelectedDayType {
  current?: { focus: () => {}} // current is optional
}

const calendarSelectedDayRef: CalendarSelectedDayType = {}

if (calendarSelectedDayRef.current !== null) {
   calendarSelectedDayRef.current.focus(); // possible null 
} 


// 1st way, use `!`  to tell typescript you sure there is current()
if (calendarSelectedDayRef.current !== null) {
   calendarSelectedDayRef.current!.focus();
} 

// 2nd way, use `?` optional chainging. if current is null, focus will not be called
calendarSelectedDayRef.current?.focus();
```

I make a playground file for you to look at
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwDYRAEzlAZQiwUhwBE4BPAFSoAcUBvAWAChlkEBXKKbMAH4AXMibIYAex4BnUQAoAlMgC8APjEBfTex1t2CSSBlgumbHkLEIpCBWoAlCDFHosufERJlKtBihUtdnZgGGR5BHMPK287XycYADoePgFkAEIVQJBuDAxlVg5OSPdLLxsfR2dk3n5wRKlZJQBuXWRgtgB6TuQARhNkAHdqABpkbhkUAAN0qc4wSWRIPKX-GQQoYHpTKkluZBleFDAAC2gUYBkuWoElELCIqLLrW3sqBJrU8Ays5By8grsThmUqeF6Vd7VFJ1MDpBrSCYtNodbrIABMuCGo3Gk2QU0Ec0k22ARkwXBOcFAAHNqYlkKFrl9TJc-rkMGNGhMhsAViBJKYAEYoEpYHAGJ5g2JvD7QgSCeFNRTNdpsIA

Comment: You're checking for `null` but an optional property would be `undefined`.

Comment: yes. those 2 ways only handle `null` situations.